# Get attribute of EC2 created via LaunchConfiguration

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I would like to get the PrivateIP attribute of EC2s that i create via LaunchConfiguration.

I need that attribute so that i can assign a type A dns record to the instance for other purposes.

Here is my code:

```
Resources:
    webLaunchConfig:
      Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'
      Properties:
        ImageId: !Ref webEc2AMI
        InstanceType: !Ref ec2WebInstanceType
        SecurityGroups: !Ref webEc2SG
        UserData:
          'Fn::Base64': !Sub >
            #!/bin/bash -xe

            apt update -y
    dnsWebServerName:
      Type: 'AWS::Route53::RecordSet'
      Properties:
        HostedZoneId: !Ref hostedZoneId
        Comment: DNS name for my db server.
        Name: !Ref dnsWebServerNamePar
        Type: A
        TTL: '900'
        ResourceRecords:
          - !GetAtt webLaunchConfig.PrivateIp
```

... and when i try to launch it i get this error:

> Template contains errors.: Template error: resource webLaunchConfig
> does not support attribute type PrivateIp in Fn::GetAtt

... indicating me that what i am trying to do is not supported. Though there must be a way to achieve this.

Do you know how to do it? Or a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you **can't do this**. `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` is only a blueprint of an instance to be launched. Thus it does not provide information about instance `PrivateIp`. The get the `PrivateIp` you have to actually launch the instance.

To do so you have to use [AWS::EC2::Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html). However `AWS::EC2::Instance` does not support launching from ``AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration`. So either you have to change your` LaunchConfiguration`into`LaunchTemplate`or just create instance directly using`AWS::EC2::Instance` rather then any templates.

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually launch template might do the trick for me. But how would i access the private ip of an ec2 created via launchtemplate? I am reading the documentation but i can't seem to find a way to GetAtt  it. Maybe i am just having trouble in traversing the aws docs

Comment: @BabaNew You careate `AWS::EC2::Instance` from your launch template using [LaunchTemplate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-launchtemplate) property. Once instance is created, you can get its private ip from its [return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#aws-properties-ec2-instance-return-values).